# Avoid global css getting overridden in PROD - REACT-NEXT app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-typescript

I've no clue how to fix this as am new to REACT-NEXT (am an Angular guy). Below is element that am utilizing from another resource like

```
import example-custom-ele-parent, {example-custom-ele-child} from 'custom-tags/example-custom'

    <example-custom-ele-parent> 
      <example-custom-ele-child></example-custom-ele-child>
    </example-custom-ele-parent>
```

when I see css for `example-custom-ele-child` in my **localhost:3008** , in chrome browser, it is like

```
.cqAcqQ {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

I want to add one rule so added in **globals.css** file, like

```
.cqAcqQ {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: 1rem solid red !important; // newly added by me
}
```

Everything was working in my localhost fine. But after i deployed, the changes i made overridden with new random class and its became

```
.kXIDVb {
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

Current package versions are

```
"next": "13.0.7",
"next-transpile-modules": "10.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

I tried override by doing `<example-custom-ele-child className={style['my-change']}></example-custom-ele-child>` but getting error like **className={style['my-change']** is not allowed

Could someone please guide me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you use inline styles?

Comment: Nope. Getting @GabrielLupu 
getting error **Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & example-customProps'"**

Answer (score 2):

**First topic - class name change**

**Answer:** by the name of the class **cqAcqQ** I am suspecting this is a auto generated class which means with each build it will have a new name. In this case it changed to **kXIDVb**. Maybe you are using a third party component like material-ui or bootstrap. they seem to generate random classNames with each build. If you share the child element code I can confirm you.

**Second Topic - why adding className to component not working**

**Answer:** the reason is you are putting the className property to a custom component. If you want to add className like this

```
<example-custom-ele-child className="test-classname" />
```

you need to make sure in the definition of this component you are handling this prop. for ex.

```
const ExampleCustomEleChild = ({ className }) => {
    // you can also put the className directly in this div or whatever html element you have
    return (
        <div className={className}>test div here</div>
    )
}
```

Let me know if it helps or you can comment here with your questions.

Comment: hello @obydul-islam-khan .. thank for looking my issue. in my case I'm not using **material-ui or bootstrap**. I'm using the framework designed by our react development team and we're consume their libraries. and I tired your solution its NOT working for me

Comment: getting error **Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & example-customProps'"**

Comment: @Mr.Learner can you please provide the details of this component - <example-custom-ele-child>
also if this is a entirely custom framework, then do you have any documentation of the components you are using? if yes then search there which props handles the className? or how to add style. if it is a public one, you can share here and I can check.

Comment: Yes i verified documentation, they mentioned about padding and margin only. nothing about borders

Comment: what I understood so far, you custom library component only have support for padding and margin. From your question you are trying to add extra margin to the component. 
margin: 2rem !important;
Maybe add the margin they way it is mentioned in the doc. and regarding support for border or other styling attributes, you can ask the development team what supports you need. Maybe they can provide support for style props so that you can add whatever style you need.

Comment: Apologies. its **border** not margin i updated my question

Comment: can you please add the details of the mentioned example-custom-ele-child component in the question? One workaround could be, you can wrap it with a div and add styling in the div. that way you don't need any updates in the component. if you provide the details/description of the component maybe I can suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add styles like so:

```
<el className="yourClassName" style={{ margin: "2rem" }}></el>
```

But if u need to add something like font-size, in this case:

```
<el className="yourClassName" style={{ fontSize: "2rem" }}></el>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: getting error **Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & example-customProps'"**